# Passing day, month and year values to 2 seperate objects(start date, endDate)

Tags: java, object, methods

How to Pass user inputed day, month and year values to 2 seperate objects
(start date, endDate) and print a summary later. struggling with the logic

```
public int promptForYear() {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the year - for example '2020': ");
    year = input.nextInt();
    return year;
}

public int promptForMonth() {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter month number - for example '6': ");
    month = input.nextInt();
    return month;
}

public int promptForday() {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the day number - for example '21': ");
    day = input.nextInt();
    return day;
}
```

Comment: But what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is iterating over the day, month and year methods twice and storing the results separately, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

First, declare `input`, `year`, `month`, and `day` as local variables. The code above doesn't include declarations, which makes me think they must be declared as instance fields, but they are only used locally, so should be declared as local variables:

```
public int promptForYear() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the year - for example '2020': ");
    int year = input.nextInt();
    return year;
}

public int promptForMonth() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter month number - for example '6': ");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    return month;
}

public int promptForDay() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the day number - for example '21': ");
    int day = input.nextInt();
    return day;
}
```

Since `year`, `month`, and `day` are only used in the return statement, you could inline them:

```
public int promptForYear() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the year - for example '2020': ");
    return input.nextInt();
}

public int promptForMonth() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter month number - for example '6': ");
    return input.nextInt();
}

public int promptForDay() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the day number - for example '21': ");
    return input.nextInt();
}
```

Then, create a method that calls each in turn and creates a `LocalDate`:

```
public LocalDate promptForDate() {
    int year = promptForYear();
    int month = promptForMonth();
    int day = promptForDay();
    return LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
}
```

Then, call that once for each date:

```
public void promptForStartAndEndDates() {
    System.out.println("Start date:");
    LocalDate startDate = promptForDate();
    System.out.println("End date:");
    LocalDate endDate = promptForDate();
    System.out.printf("%tF - %tF", startDate, endDate); // prints the range, e.g., "2020-01-19 - 2021-06-16"
}
```

Comment: Works a treat, thank you very much for the detailed description, If I wanted to store the startDate and endDate for printing in the future. would I need to declare the them as instance fields